# Is it Possible to Add a Test Project to a WPF Solution that Targets .NET 5.0?

Tags: .net, tdd

Trying to update my WPF app to target .NET 5.0. However, I am getting the following error message

```
Project WpfWithTest is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Project WpfWithTest supports: net5.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
```

If I change my WPF app to target *".NET Core 3.1 (Long-term support)"*, the problem goes away, but I want to target the latest version.

Also, there are several types of test projects available, but all of them seem give me the same error.

When I try updating the my test project, modifying Target Framework, to 5.0, it doesn't help (see screen shot below).

Bottom Line is that it only works if both projects target .NET 3.1
[image: Screen shot shows how I tried to change my test project to target .NET 5.0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test WPF projects, the test project framework also needs to be set to `net-5.0-windows`.

Double-click on the test project in Visual Studio to open the `.cspoj` file for the tests.

Then change the target framework to `net5.0-windows`.

```xml
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

I can't find any way to do this using the Properties UI, while leaving the project as a console application. When the above settings are applied, the Properties UI shows the target framework as unset.

Comment: Thanks Scroog1, it worked! Editing that XML project file is always a bit intimidating. At least they revised Visual Studio so you no longer need to unload the project to perform the edit.